# ¿Asignar imagen por codigo a ImageView - Android?

Tags: java, android

Que parametros debe llevar este metodo para asignarle una imagen de la carpeta de Drawable a la imagen, o si se usa otro metodo para esto.

```
ImageView image;
image.setImageResource("?");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes ingresar el id de tu imagen.

Por ejemplo, si tu drawable se llama  "imagen_test.png"
El código quedaría así :

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen_test);
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo había redescubierto, pero me toca darte la respuesta correcta.